# How to start Learn Prism for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, prism-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Learn Prism for Silverlight Fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799749/how-to-learn-prism-for-silverlight-fast)

I want to learn and implement PRISM in My new application.

Please suggests any link which is good for how to start with prism and how to implement it in application.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Codeproject site for start http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/PrismTutorial_Part1.aspx
I also encourage purchasing a monthly subscription of Pluralsight. There you will find video tutorials that everything a developer needs.