# How to Learn Prism for Silverlight Fast?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, prism-4

I need to make Silverlight application With Prism. What could be best way to learn to make simple application with Silverlight + Prism? Also suggest any Good books for same.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great book, I started with this book myself:

[Developer’s Guide to Microsoft® Prism 4: Building Modular MVVM Applications with Windows® Presentation Foundation and Microsoft Silverlight®](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145315496.do)

Comment: Is the linked book different in content to the following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx ? I have been using this as a guide, and the ToC looks the same.

Comment: @BenP -> yes, same ISBN.  It's a Microsoft book and both links ultimately to to O'Reilly

Answer (score 4):

I also have the book mentioned by 'daageu', and would also recommend it.

But to accelerate the process of learning Prism even faster, I recommend the video series presented by Mike Taulty and available for free on [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/mtaulty/prism--silverlight-part-1-taking-sketched-code-towards-unity).

It's a nine part series, and his introduction to the Unity Container, for example, is about the best you'll get, and you'll be up to speed on that component in about an hour.

Once you have downloaded and watched the videos, you can use the book as a vehicle to become an expert.

NOTE:  actually, the 'quick starts' included in the kit are pretty transparent and understandable as well...

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Taulty videos. He creates an app without using prism and then slowly integrates different pieces of Prism into his app so you can see the motivation behind each of the patterns.

Answer (score 0):

look this url, it will be helpful for you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/229931/Understand-MVVM-Using-PRISM-by-Hello-World-Silverl